# How to stationarize profit and loss data with an increasing variance and large negative values for time series analysis?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, finance

PnL can take large negative values, and its variance increases over time as the firm grows. If we do differencing, an increasing variance remains. If we take log, negative values cannot be defined. How do you stationarize this type of data for time series analysis? Please assume that we cannot decompose PnL into underlying factors such as profits and losses, which can be experessed as positive and modeled separately.

Comment: Please spell out PnL. What does that stand for?

Comment: @gung Profit and Loss.

Comment: Does the growth in variance remain with multiple lags?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115271/transforming-a-time-series-with-a-negative-number Either way, see accepted answer therein.

Comment: What's the length of series? Frequency?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the measure you mentioned is the outcome of a profit and loss statement which is either a profit **or** a loss. One way is to divide the profit by the total assets of the company to arrive at the ROA (return on assets). 
$$
ROA_{t}=\frac{{\rm Profit}_t}{{\rm Total\ Assets}_{t-1}}
$$
where Profit can be positive or negative (in this case we call it a loss).

It might be worth investigating whether the ROA time series is stationary.

Answer (score 0):

I typically scale PnL by some measure of wealth or invested capital. That way, I can log difference wealth into something reasonably stationary.